# How to say "Serving for # people"?

Tags: translation, words

I have a class project and I have to write a recipe. On it I'm trying to write something along the lines of "Serving for x people".

What would be a good way to say that phrase?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [人前｛ひとまえ｝ and 人前｛にんまえ｝](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27598/%e4%ba%ba%e5%89%8d-%e3%81%b2%e3%81%a8%e3%81%be%e3%81%88-and-%e4%ba%ba%e5%89%8d-%e3%81%ab%e3%82%93%e3%81%be%e3%81%88)

Comment: Related, but not even close to duplicate. That's one possible answer off many.

Answer (score 6):

I think that 〜人分 works to mean "serves X people", e.g. ３人分 means "serves three people".

Source: http://cookpad.com/recipe/2524181

Comment: +1 - In my cooking classes in High School they used ～人分 on the recipes we used.

Answer (score 4):

One possible phrase to use when ordering a serving is 人前{にんまえ}, like 一人前{いちにんまえ}, 二人前{ににんまえ}, 三人前{さんにんまえ}...

A proper suffix used for counting servings, but generally used only by waiters and cooks is 丁{ちょう}, like ラーメン１丁{いっちょう}頂きました (when waiter "passes" the order to the kitchen).