# Describing things made of many parts

Tags: grammar

I have encountered many grammatical structures used when describing things made of many parts, each one corresponding to a single grammatical structure in English:
[numeral] [thing counted] [thing described]

1. 3階建て 3 storey building
2. 3ページ**の**本 3 page book
3. 3本**足**の椅子 3 legged chair
4. 3人**の**女性会社 3 woman company
5. 3匹の犬**の**囲い 3 dog enclosure

I would like to know if there are rules to know which pattern to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic pattern is fairly simple also in Japanese: `number + counter + の + noun`. 3ページの本 follows this pattern pretty straightforwardly.

- You can think -階建て and -本足 are basically counters on their own (although I don't know if they are true counters; some dictionaries may classify them as suffixes). Note that you have to say 3階建ての建物 to say "3-story *building*". There are a few long and specific "counters" like these, which you have to remember along with the meanings. Other examples include -人組, [-人乗り](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%BA%BA%E4%B9%97%E3%82%8A), [-人前](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/27625/5010), [-本撮り](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E6%9C%AC%E6%92%AE%E3%82%8A) and [-枚落ち](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicap_(shogi)). These types of expressions are small in number and are rarely coined.
- 3人の女性会社 literally means "three-person woman-company", but I'm not sure what 女性会社 refers to. 女性会社 sounds like this is a [compound word with some special meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/27487/5010). If you want to say "a company consisting of three women", use 女性3人の会社.
- As for 3匹の犬の囲い, 3匹の犬 perfectly follows the pattern above. ～の囲い means something like "the fence for ～", but this part has nothing to do with counting things.

[image]